# Changing sprite nodes parent after TouchesEnded

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, parent-child, sprite

I'm attempting to change the parent node of a sprite after it is dropped, but I'm getting a nil error.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        SKSpriteNode *gamePiece = [self pickObject];
        gamePiece.position = location;
        gamePiece.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

        [self addChild:gamePiece];

        _currentTouch = touch;
        currentGamePiece = gamePiece;

        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];

        if(touchLocation.y > 350)
        {
            _bg.position = CGPointMake(_bg.position.x, _bg.position.y-2);
        }
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        if ([touch isEqual:_currentTouch])
        {
            currentGamePiece.position = location;
        }

        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];

        if(touchLocation.y > 350)
        {
            _bg.position = CGPointMake(_bg.position.x, _bg.position.y-2);
        }
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        if ([touch isEqual:_currentTouch])
        {
            currentGamePiece.position = location;
            currentGamePiece.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;

            SKAction *removeNode = [SKAction removeFromParent];
            [gamePiece runAction: removeNode];

            [_bg addChild:gamePiece];
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe it has something to do with the switch to "currentGamePiece", but when I try to remove "currentGamePiece" from its parent, I get an error like "attempting to add node that already has a parent". I may just not be going about it the right way. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this code...

```
        SKAction *removeNode = [SKAction removeFromParent];
        [gamePiece runAction: removeNode];

        [_bg addChild:gamePiece];
```

with this...

```
        [gamePiece removeFromParent];
        [_bg addChild:gamePiece];
```

The issue is gamePiece is added to the _gb before the SKAction has a chance to remove it from its parent. The app crashes because a node can't have two parents.